# How to update Saleor's Graphql responses with newly added DB table fields?

Tags: graphql, saleor

First, Saleor with GraphQL is fantastic. Just love it.

The products we are selling have additional metadata we need to get from Graphql.  Out of the box, the Graphql queries work fine, such as:

```
{
  product (id: "UHJvZHVjdDo3Mg==") {
    id
    name
    description
  }
}
```

What I need to do is expose data from my products table with additional columns, such as productInfo1, productInfo2, and productInfo3.  This part is easy of course.

However, I am struggling with how to update the Saleor Graphql so I can run a query like the following:

```
{
  product (id: "UHJvZHVjdDo3Mg==") {
    id
    name
    description {
      productInfo1
      productInfo2
      productInfo3
    }
  }
}
```

I have been through the Saleor docs, Stack Overflow, and a variety of blogs...  I've attempted some logical approaches myself, without any success.

I'm eager to start working on these types of updates for our needs here.  Any suggestions or links to "how to" locations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to add subfields to description there is a couple of things you have to do:

1. Create new description object type which contains the subfields you want, e.g.:

```py
class ProductDescription(graphene.ObjectType):
    productInfo1 = graphene.String()
    productInfo2 = graphene.String()
    productInfo3 = graphene.String()
```

2. Set the `description` field with the new type under `Product` type:

```py
class Product(CountableDjangoObjectType):
    ...
    description = graphene.Field(ProductDescription)
```

3. Add resolver for `description` under `Product` type:

```py
def resolve_description(self, info):
    return ProductDescription(
        productInfo1=self.description,
        productInfo2='Some additional info',
        productInfo3='Some more additional info',
    )
```

Saleor's GraphQL API is based on the [Graphene](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene) framework. You can find more about resolvers and object types here: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/#resolvers.

Comment: Thanks Paffer.  I'll try this out tomorrow morning.

Comment: Hey Paffer, this will be useful for sure, but I think I wasn't quite clear enough.  I was trying to add a new column to an existing table already being exposed through Saleor GraphQL.  Also, and almost more important, I'm facing the need to create a new DB table and expose it through Graphql.  Would you be able to give me some guidance/examples on that?  I've been searching for a couple of days without a clear answer.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hey Bob, could you give some more details? I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. You wrote in your question that you were able to add new columns and expose them under Product in GraphQL API, right? I thought you only wanted to make the field nested.

Comment: If you want the `description` field on `Product` model to be a `ForeignKey` to your new `ProductDescription` model (i.e. a new separate table), then you would have to create a proper GraphQL type for it. You can do this by creating a class in `graphql/product/types/products.py` which inherits from `DjangoObjectType` and has `model = ProductDescription` in it's `Meta`. Check out the example in https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#full-example. If you do this, the API will automatically pick up this new type and you'll be able to query it.

Comment: Thanks Paffer. I'll look into that this afternoon.

Comment: HI Paffer,  Those graphene python docs are nice and easy to read. Thanks.   I'm trying to match up the differences between those and how Saleor has Graphql files setup.  I hope to figure it out soon.  Thanks